# Assembler 8086: Half input array and one single output

Tags: arrays, assembly, input, output, x86-16

I've tried to compile and run this simple program:

```
DIM EQU 10
    .MODEL small
    .STACK
    .DATA
VETT DB DIM DUP(?)
    .CODE
    .STARTUP
    MOV CX,DIM
    MOV DI,0
    MOV AH,1
lab1:   INT 21H
        MOV VETT[DI], AL
        INC DI
        DEC CX
        CMP CX,0
        JNZ lab1
        MOV CX,DIM
        MOV AH,2
lab2:   DEC DI
        MOV DL, VETT[DI]
        INT 21H
        DEC CX
        CMP CX,0
        JNZ lab2
    .EXIT
    END
```

When I try to insert values in the array, I can only insert five values instead of ten as I declare in the first line "DIM EQU 10". Then, after that, the program only show me the first value inserted in the array.

I'm running this program on MASM611 with DOSBOX 0.74 on a Mac OS X 10.9. Anyone can understand why I can only insert five values and I get only one value as output? How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juding by the behaviour you describe, I'm guessing that you're inputting something like this:

```
1 <Return>
2 <Return>
3 <Return>
4 <Return>
5 <Return>
```

However,  `INT 21H / AH=01H` does not wait for the Return key to be pressed, so each time you press Return that counts as an additional character.

If you just input this instead:

`1234567890`

the program responds with

`0987654321`

as expected.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. Thank you very much for your help.